# Confluent control-center throws error after 1 minute when viewing the messages on any topic in UI

Tags: confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

I have setup confluent 5.5.0 on kubernetes (AKS) using "cp-helm-charts", however, I am facing some issue with the control center. Everytime I am on the messages window of a topic in control center ui, the below error shows up after 1 minute.

It works fine for 1 minute and then the error pops up. If I navigate to any other section in the UI or even refresh and come back then it again works for 1 minute and then the error pops up.

[image]